# Set up apache proxy with openAM cert auth - set header if GET parameter is present

Tags: apache, authentication, http-headers, certificate, openam

Cert-based authentication in OpenAM need to set http header X-Client-Cert. I want use apache as reverse proxy and to set this header, when url is /openam/UI/Login?module=PKI.

/openam/UI/Login is for username and password authentication.

I have this configuration:

```
...
  ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/ 
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/ 

  RequestHeader set X-Client-Cert ""

  <Location "/openam/UI/Login/PKI">
    RequestHeader set X-Client-Cert  "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLVerifyClient require
  </Location>

  RewriteRule /openam/UI/Login/PKI balancer://mycluster/openam/UI/Login?module=PKI [P]
...
```

and it can do the trick, but the cost is rewrite of
/openam/UI/Login?module=PKI
to
/openam/UI/Login/PKI
and I don't like it.

Can you advice me how to do it without this rewrite?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With apache2.4 I can do it with:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /module=PKI/">
    RequestHeader set X-Client-Cert  "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s"
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLVerifyClient require
<Else>
    RequestHeader set X-Client-Cert ""
</If>
```

Comment: Great to know about these new features. I've just upgraded various of our servers from 2.2 to 2.4 myself and had used SetEnvIf in the past. Can see myself using this in future instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible using a combination of `SetEnvIf` and `RequestHeader`.

Use `SetEnvIf` to set a variable indicating that the URI is for the right path:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/openam/UI/Login?module=PKI" x_client_cert=1
```

And use the optional `env=[!]variable` parameter to `RequestHeader`:

```
RequestHeader set X-Client-Cert "%{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s" x_client_cert=1
```

I've probably got the syntax slightly wrong -- in particular possibly the escaping and format of the second (URI) parameter to SetEnvIf, but this approach should work.

Documentation links:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader

Comment: looking at [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) and there is:
Request_URI - the resource requested on the HTTP request line -- generally the portion of the URL following the scheme and host portion **without the query string**. See the RewriteCond directive of mod_rewrite for extra information on how to match your query string.

I need querystring, so going to RewriteCond directive link [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). To decide by query string I need something like this:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^module=PKI

Comment: Sorry, I missed that! Hmm, then we're back to rewriting which is what you wanted to avoid. I presume you're currently on 2.2; can you upgrade to 2.4? The embedded LUA engine might be useful for this, but not sure if it will be faster or more efficient.

Comment: Apache 2.4 has the <If> directive which can be used for per-request configuration! The example on [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if) page even uses the query string.

Comment: Yes, If directive will do the trick, tested and posted as separate answer, thanks for your time.